# Which exception type to use for a sanity check?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm writing software in .NET which requires runtime sanity checks, even in release mode, which means `Debug.Assert` and `Trace.Assert` are inappropriate (as `Debug.Assert` only works when the `DEBUG` symbol is defined, and `Trace.Assert` doesn't cause program termination). The runtime sanity check is necessary because there is a non-zero probability of invalid incoming data.

An immediate solution is to use `Environment.FailFast` with an explanatory message, but I'd prefer to throw some kind of exception - and I'd really not like to throw my own custom exception because my code could be called by other code which does not have a reference to my assembly, so they would be unable to catch it without catching `System.Exception`.

Surprisingly, the standard .NET Framework does not ship with any kind of `RuntimeAssertException`, `ThisShouldNeverHappenException` or `UnacceptableUnexpectedDataException` - granted, that's what `System.Exception` is meant to represent ("exceptional" circumstances) - except Best Practices prohibit throwing `System.Exception` directly. Furthermore `ApplicationException` is effectively deprecated and is only meant for use in non-fatal situations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception(v=vs.71).aspx

> `ApplicationException` Class - The exception that is thrown when a non-fatal application error occurs.

Using `InvalidOperationException` is a cop-out, but it isn't entirely appropriate because my particular scenario relates to incoming data.

Here's an example:

```
public void ProcessData() {

    // Input:
    MyDataType incomingData = this.dataSource.ReadFromExternalSource();

    // Sanity check:
    if( incomingData.Foo != 1 ) throw ...;
    if( incomingData.Bar != "baz" ) throw ...;
    if( incomingData.Items.Count <= 123 ) throw ...;

    // Do work:
    this.turboEncabulator.ApplyCapacitativeDiractance( incomingData.Bar, ref incomingData.Foo );

    // Output:
    this.dataSink.Output( incomingData );
}
```

- Using `ArgumentException` is inappropriate because the `incomingData` is not actually an argument.

  - While there is `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` there is no `LocalVariableOutOfRangeException` which might be more appropriate.
- In this contrived example, `InvalidOperationException` would be valid as it concerns to the state of `incomingData`, but in my example the interaction between objects is more complex.
- As the `TurboEncabulator` just processes raw numbers, it's the responsibility of the `ProcessData` method to ensure the data is within the correct domain bounds, which is why `ApplyCapacitativeDiractance` won't throw any `ArgumentException` values.

#### Updates:

Regarding this comment by Alireza:

> It's a bit strange that a caller can call (or execute) your application and yet it doesn't have access to its assembly! Can you elaborate how this call is done?

Assemblies can be loaded at runtime and code can call into them without ever making a reference to that assembly at build-time, for example this code might exist in third-party code:

```
Assembly externalAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MyAssembly.dll");
Type externalType = externalAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar.DataProcessor");
Object dataProcessorInstance = Activator.CreateInstance();
MethodInfo method = externalType.GetMethod("ProcessData");
try {
    method.Invoke( dataProcessorInstance, null ); // <-- throws
} catch(...) { // <-- no reference exists, so this code cannot be specific about the exception it catches if the type is defiend in MyAssembly.dll
    // handle error gracefully
}
```

Comment: It's a bit strange that a caller can call (or execute) your application and yet it doesn't have access to its assembly! Can you elaborate how this call is done?

Comment: so you need to check your incoming data and throw the appropriate exception - like argumentexception

Comment: Can you elaborate regarding why the incoming data is not an argument or arguments?

Comment: @Alireza Runtime loading with `Assembly.Load` and an interface call. Remember that .NET doesn't have checked exceptions like Java does.

Comment: If you've got an interface, you've got an assembly that your program and its clients both must reference; can you put custom exceptions in there? They are conceptually part of the "interface" (API), right?

Comment: @Dai Blorgbeard is correct. You can put exceptions in the assembly and make them public.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: How about returning a result, instead of throwing exceptions. Say a structure with "OK/Fail" enum and a message string.

Comment: If you want a system exception, conceivably [`InvalidDataException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception.aspx) could be a fit.

Comment: Ah, there's no shared assembly or `interface`, it's 100% reflection? My first comment doesn't apply then.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a single absolute answer to this question, I think it's a matter of opinion. That said, in my opinion, I believe you should create a new custom exception type that derives from `System.Exception`. The issue you've described about the caller not having access to your types is a separate problem. If you didn't have this scenario, the solution would be clear, you'd create a custom exception. I argue this is still the case. With the unique situation you have, where the caller is using `Assembly.Load` and therefore doesn't have direct access to your types at compile time, I'd suggest they can still catch the exception as `System.Exception` in this case (remember this isn't as bad now that this no longer catches everything by default, see the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute). They can then use reflection to load information on your exception type in the same way they must have to call your method in the first place, or use the type name, and can re-throw the exception if it isn't the one they wanted to catch. If you're using C# 6, you can also use an exception filter to make this cleaner.

**EDIT:** Based on your added code snippet, here's how I suggest this could be done:

```
Assembly externalAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MyAssembly.dll");
Type externalType = externalAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar.DataProcessor");
Type exceptionType = externalAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar.MyCustomException");
Object dataProcessorInstance = Activator.CreateInstance();
MethodInfo method = externalType.GetMethod("ProcessData");
try
{
    method.Invoke( dataProcessorInstance, null ); // <-- throws
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
    if(!exceptionType.IsAssignableFrom(ex.GetType()))
    {
        throw;
    }
    // handle error gracefully
}
```

And if you have C# 6 support (VS2015+), the better way to do it is with exception filters, as follows:

```
Assembly externalAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MyAssembly.dll");
Type externalType = externalAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar.DataProcessor");
Type exceptionType = externalAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar.MyCustomException");
Object dataProcessorInstance = Activator.CreateInstance();
MethodInfo method = externalType.GetMethod("ProcessData");
try
{
    method.Invoke( dataProcessorInstance, null ); // <-- throws
}
catch(System.Exception ex) when (exceptionType.IsAssignableFrom(ex.GetType()))
{
    // handle error gracefully
}
```